# Vanity p-trap installation question

Tags: plumbing

I am installing a new p-trap under my new vanity. The depth from the wall of the new vanity is about 6 inches shorter than the old and the tailpiece for the sink is now closer to the wall than before. Given the shorter distance from the tailpiece to the wall, I have been unable to match the j-bend with the trap arm even if I shorten the trap arm. The only way I have been able to hook it up is by rotating the pieces as shown in the picture.
[image: ptrap]

All the pieces don't make an even plane with the wall. Is this acceptable and/or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does it work? If so I'd be *very* tempted to leave it be.

Comment: Its not leaking.  I just like to do the things the right way if at all possible.

Comment: I don't know if any building codes apply here, but I can't see any argument from the physics side of things - it should work just as well.

Answer (score 4):

Looks perfectly okay to me. I've seen p-traps and s-traps in worse configurations.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the non-square joints still have a good seal, you can undo the p-trap and then put a little [pipe thread sealant](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=t+plus+2+pipe+thread+sealant&cid=18390451752636405863&os=sellers#) in the joints and on the threads (and then tighten everything back together again).  The pipe thread sealant will give you an extra little bit of seal and comes in handy when the joints are not making a neat and clean connection.